# Is there a clever way to set a total duration for a sequence of SKActions?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, sequence, skaction

I think the answer is no, but here’s what I’m doing and I’ll then show what I wish I could do.  Overall, what I’m going for is a sequence of dampening rotations that total 24 seconds total.

```
#define START_ANGLE         M_PI/4.0
#define SPRING_TENSION      0.9
#define START_DURATION      1.3     // Hack!

NSMutableArray *animationA = [NSMutableArray array];
double a = START_ANGLE;
double d = START_DURATION;
while (a * a > 0.01) {
    // Bounce to the other side.
    SKAction *a1 = [SKAction rotateToAngle:a duration:d];
    a1.timingMode = SKActionTimingEaseIn;
    [animationA addObject:a1];

    // Return to rest
    SKAction *a2 = [SKAction rotateToAngle:0 duration:d];
    a2.timingMode = SKActionTimingEaseOut;
    [animationA addObject:a2];

    // Reduce the height of the bounce by the spring's tension
    a *= -SPRING_TENSION;
    d *= SPRING_TENSION;
}
SKAction *seqA = [SKAction sequence:animationA];
[mySprite runAction:seqA];
```

What I want is for the total sequence duration to be 24 seconds and for the intervening actions to be inferred from that.  Since the API doesn’t allow that, in order to arrive at this solution I had to precompute how many iterations of the loop there’d be and track the angle’s attentuation in order to arrive at START_DURATION.

It’s hacky and inflexible -- bad enough that I had to unroll the loop to figure out each component duration, but what if I want to change the SPRING_TENSION later but maintain the total duration?  I’d have to unroll the loop again and recompute START_DURATION.

I wish I could do something more flexible like this:

```
#define START_ANGLE         M_PI/4.0
#define SPRING_TENSION      0.9
#define TOTAL_DURATION      24.0

NSMutableArray *animationA = [NSMutableArray array];
double a = START_ANGLE;
while (a * a > 0.01) {
    // Bounce to the other side.
    SKAction *a1 = [SKAction rotateToAngle:a];  // Duration will be computed from total duration
    a1.timingMode = SKActionTimingEaseIn;
    [animationA addObject:a1];

    // Return to rest
    SKAction *a2 = [SKAction rotateToAngle:0];  // Duration will be computed from total duration
    a2.timingMode = SKActionTimingEaseOut;
    [animationA addObject:a2];

    // Reduce the height of the bounce by the spring's tension
    a *= -SPRING_TENSION;
    d *= SPRING_TENSION;
}
SKAction *seqA = [SKAction sequence:animationA duration:TOTAL_DURATION];      // This computes all undefined component durations
[mySprite runAction:seqA];
```

That way, I get what I want:  I get an animation sequence of a chosen duration and let the framework figure out the intervening rotations.  This is akin to how keyframes are inferred by CAKeyframeAnimation.  Is there a clever way to do this with SpriteKit that I’ve overlooked?

Comment: There is a subtlety here that I'm not getting. Please edit your question and explain why `SKAction *a1 = [SKAction rotateToAngle:a duration:TOTAL_DURATION / 2];` doesn't meet your needs.

Comment: Notice that the loop runs many times and the duration of each rotation back and forth decreases each time, in step with the amount of each rotation.  As in the CAKeyframeAnimation paradigm, keyframes are inferred by dividing the overall animation.

Comment: Does [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skkeyframesequence) help?